# SSIS Deployment Wizard - No Servers available in the Select Destination

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, ssms

I'm trying to deploy my first Integration package and ran into a issue. I've searched around but I couldn't find any answers, so I guess I'm missing something really basic.

I created a package in Visual Code, and trying to deploy it, but when I get to the Select Destination part of the Deployment Wizard, when I press "Browse" I can't find the local server(the MININT-4CBK9MP one).

I have SSMS and Visual Code 2019 Community Edition. I have created the SSISDB folder inside SSMS.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: *"I have SSMS and Visual Code 2019 Community Edition"* But have you installed SQL Server? Also Visual Code 2019? VS Code doesn't have year vefsioning. Do you means Visual Studio? Either way, both are IDEs; you need to install SQL Server to be able to deploy a package.

Comment: I've installed a new instance on Sql Server, and now I can see both of them in Network Servers. No clue what was the problem, but....

Comment: Btw, thanks for your comment, it pushed me to do a new install :)